# Excel Addin testing in various environments

Tags: excel, visual-studio, testing, vsto, excel-addins

I have developed a VSTO add-in for Excel and created a setup file to install.

Its working fine in office 365/win10, but I want to check how it performs in different office versions such as 2016, 2019 or 365.

How can i do that ? Is there a smarter way to do it within Visual studio or do i need to create virtual pc for each environment and test them one by one.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a VM and test your MSI there for each supported platform/OS/Excel version. There is no smarter way for that.